# Voltar 2 páginas com php / criar sessão da última URL acessada

Tags: codeigniter, login, session

Gostaria de saber como faço para criar uma sessão da última url acessada, o porque disso:
Tenho um sistema de login no site que se a pessoa clicar em comprar no produto e não estiver logada, ela é direcionada para a página de login, após fazer o login, ela é redirecionada para a home com um redirect: `redirect('/user/painel');`
Só que preciso que após ela logar, ela volte pra última url acessada para poder comprar o produto que ela clicou.
Ou talvez algum header location que volte duas páginas.
Obs: O framework que estou utilizando é o Codeigniter
Tentei utilizar também: `header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "");` porém só volta uma página, preciso que volte duas.

Comment: Isso não resolve?

$_SESSION['ultimaUrl'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Comment: Na verdade não, porque a ultima url acessada é a página de login.. na verdade preciso que volte a segunda url anterior, exemplo: produto clicando/pagina de login/logado   - preciso que volte para produto clicando não para pagina de login

Comment: acho que usando a ideia do Eduardo seria na pagina de login vc verificar se existe algo nessa `ultimaUrl` e dai quando o usuário clicar em logar vc ou manda ele para seu `user/painel` ou vc manda ele para essa ultima url.

Comment: Se a aplicação é assim, não deveria existir o redirect para a home, mas sim para a página que "pediu" o login. Um dos jeitos mais simples é passar o retorno no URL. `http://paginadelogin.php?retorno=/produto012.php` - Se o retorno for em branco (ou contiver caracteres inválidos e/ou não começar por uma barram o que pode indicar um redirect forjado), redireciona pra home, senão redireciona pro retorno.

Comment: É que oque acontece, eu tenho vários produtos, e na interna de cada um tem o botão comprar, se a pessoa não está logada e clicar em comprar, ela é direcionada para a página de login, fazendo o login ela é direcionada para a home do site, só que eu queria que ao invés dela voltar pra home, ela volte para a página que ela estava onde está o produto, ou seja, duas páginas anteriores, porque a pagina anterior é a do formulário de login: interna do produto / página de login / logado. se eu der um location pra voltar pra última página, ela acaba caindo na página de login.

Comment: Então, acho que vai ser difícil solução mais simples do que a que eu postei no comentário anterior...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme visto, utilizei uma sessão:

```
$_SESSION['url_assine'] = base_url().'assinatura'.$id;
    redirect('erro/efetuar_login_assinatura');
```

e dentro do controller de erro/efetuar_login_assinatura eu pego a sessão que setei:

```
 redirect($_SESSION['url_assine']);
```